# Testing the chaincode during development

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am developing a chaincode (for Hyperledger Febric version 1.0) and testing it using the dev mode:
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html#testing-using-dev-mode

Currently, every time I make a change I bring down the network and start over. Is there a faster way of testing chaincode during development?

Answer (score 2):

While you'd eventually need to do garbage collection (e.g. tear down the network and start from scratch), you could simply give the chaincode a different name between iterations of your chaincode development.

e.g. for each iteration of your chaincode, change the `CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME` and reference that name with the `-n` argument to the `install`, `instantiate`, `invoke` or `query` commands.

```
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer:7051 CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc:0 ./sacc
```

becomes

```
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer:7051 CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc2:0 ./sacc
```

then

```
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer:7051 CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc3:0 ./sacc
```

and then be sure to use the corresponding name (**mycc**, **mycc2** and **mycc3**) in the install, instantiate and invoke, etc commands. The peer will treat each as a new chaincode.

Comment: Probably worth to mention the upgrade chaincode command which also could be used here.

Comment: With upgrade chaincode command, do I still have to instantiate the chaincode again?